# jhipster cloud foundry images

Tags: css, image, cloud-foundry, jhipster

I have succesfully deployed my JHipster Application to Cloud Foundry. But I have some problems with the images. Locally everything works fine and all the images are displayed. After the deployment the images can not be shown. The server responds with {"timestamp":1419423248553,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"","path":"/images/K.PNG"}.

I have an index.html file that is located in the same location as a folder images. The folder images contains all the pictures. Therefore I set the path to ./images/K.PNG.

The imageurl on hte server is the following.
http://nyapp.cfapps.io/images/K.PNG

Is this URL still correct?
How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: If I access the images from CSS it works. But this is not possible as I need to load them dynamicaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Trafalgar, if you're using spring boot, then all your static resources should be in src/main/resources/static

so, for your images, you should put them in:

```
src/main/resources/static/images/K.PNG
```

then, the link will work:

```
nyapp.cfapps.io/images/K.PNG
```

you will not need to create an explicit url mapping inside your app to the static resources.

Answer (score 0):

for prod builds jhipster uses the grunt plugins [rev](https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev) & [usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) to add/use versioning prefixes on static resources like images. [usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) should replace all the references on html & css files to your images using with the correct prefix. Please verify that your image references are being set on html or css/scss files